GCP - Workload Identity Federation : AccessDeniedException: 403 Permission
I’m working on a new GitLab CI pipeline with GCP. I’ve created a service account, but due to security restrictions, I cannot create an SSH key. Instead, I’m using Workload Identity Federation. I’ve set up a Pool and added my provider.
Here’s what my CI configuration looks like:
deploy_to_gae:
  stage: deploy
  id_tokens:
    ID_TOKEN:
      aud: "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../providers/..."
    SIGSTORE_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: "sigstore"
  tags:
    - runner1
  script:
    - echo ${ID_TOKEN} > .ci_jwt_v2
    - gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../providers/... --service-account="...@...iam.gserviceaccount.com" --output-file=.gcp_credentials.json --credential-source-file=.ci_jwt_v2

    - gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_credentials.json
    - cat .gcp_credentials.json
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud app deploy --quiet
  only:
    - main

However, I’m encountering this error in the logs:
$ echo ${ID_TOKEN} > .ci_jwt_v2
$ gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../providers/... --service-account="...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com" --output-file=.gcp_credentials.json --credential-source-file=.ci_jwt_v2
Created credential configuration file [.gcp_credentials.json].
$ gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_credentials.json
Authenticated with external account credentials for: [...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com].
Your current project is [None].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
$ cat .gcp_credentials.json
{
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com",
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../providers/...",
  "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",
  "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
  "credential_source": {
    "file": ".ci_jwt_v2"
  },
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken"
}$ gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
ERROR: (gcloud.config.set) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')

I’ve already granted several permissions (I’ll remove unnecessary roles later), but the error persists. Here are the permissions I’ve applied:
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/appengine.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/appengineflex.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountOpenIdTokenCreator
- members:
  - principal://iam.googleapis.com/projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../subject/...
  - principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../attribute.repository/clients/...
  - principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../attribute.repository/...
  - principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../attribute.repository/...
  - serviceAccount:...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - user:...@...
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
- members:
  - principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/.../locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/.../attribute.repository/clients/...
  - serviceAccount:...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
- members:
  - serviceAccount:...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
etag: BwYiTdmWSfM=
version: 1

If anyone has any ideas or solutions, your help would be greatly appreciated!


You are masking too much information, making detecting a mistake difficult. Use the full identity strings, just fiddle with the numbers. 2) Check the value of $PROJECT_ID. The error is that you do not have the permission iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken on a resource. I am unsure which resource, but it relates to the project ID.


I just tried auth'ing to Google Cloud from GitHub Actions and it's..... complicated. I received the same error (getAccessToken) and it was because I'd misconfigured the provider. I encourage you to double-check attribute mapping and conditions. Repository values must include the org|user. Also workloadIdentityUser should be on the Service Account not the Project.

Hi @JohnHanley, I apologize for masking certain information, but I can assure you that the issue is not related to the project ID or any specific value. I've also verified that the token generated by GitLab is valid. What do you mean by "Use the full identity strings, just fiddle with the numbers" (I'm exploring all possibilities now)

Hi @DazWilkin, thank you for your response. The workloadIdentityUser role is already assigned to the account, as seen in the last blockcode. Regarding the attribute mapping, this might indeed be the issue. I'm not sure where to define the attribute key/value in my CI pipeline. I haven't set any conditions yet as I couldn't find much information on how to do so.

When posting details in your question, show the identities modified a bit so that we can double-check the values. Search StackOverflow for other questions on WIF. Notice that in almost every case, it was a simple user mistake. By masking the information we cannot tell what that mistake is. My advice is to delete everything and start over following the docs step-by-step.

I would also create a new project to practice in and clean up the original project. Once you have documented steps, repeat in the required project.

@JohnHanley, you right, I tried to create new service account or identity pool, but not a new project. I'll try.
